# for loop is iterating printf written after scanf only once

Tags: c, for-loop, printf, scanf

I want to store array elements using for loop with a tap space.But tab is printed only once and then it doesn't work.
The code is following-

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
  int i,a[10];
  clrscr();
  printf("Enter array elements: \n");
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
     scanf("%d",&a[i]);
     printf("\t");
  }
  getch();
}
```

The output of above code is-
[Output of above code in TurboC++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSvvg.png)

I have tried CodeBlocks also but the output is same.
On the other hand when I use this code-

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i,a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
     printf("%d",a[i]);
     printf("\t");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The output is following-
[Compilor-CodeBlocks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcTmj.png)

Why the output is different for the codes?

Comment: Why are you using turbo c? It's outdated.

Comment: Hint: don't use Turbo C. This tool is older than you. There are many alternatives, and most (if not all) of them are better than Turbo C. And please, don't post pictures of text, but post text instead.

Comment: I use codeblocks mainly but using tubo for checking the code

Comment: Hey user3121023, what is benefit of adding printf statement in code then?

Comment: _" but using tubo for checking the code"_ : so why can't you "check the code" (whatever this is supposed to mean) in Codeblocks??

Comment: `scanf` puts the cursor to the beginning of the next line. That's the way `scanf` works, you can't do anything about that.

Answer (score 2):

In first code you press enter after inputting the each input thus you see new line after each entry.

In second code you are not printing newline through code nor manually.

To print new line append `\n` as below.

```
 printf("\t\n");
```

Comment: Why I am not getting a tab space after evey input? and how to enter input without pressing enter in the above code

Comment: Enter all the numbers at once and press enter only once.

Comment: You need to give space between each number while inputting.

Comment: @RohitKumarShrivastava you only asked why are those two outputs different and i believe kiran answered that. what kind of output do you actually want and what should your input look like? could you give us an example of that?

Comment: @m.k I want the output of both the codes as the output of second code.

Comment: The way @kiranBiradar told, stores that value(entered without pressing enter) to a[0] only.

Comment: @RohitKumarShrivastava well you can use a for loop just to scan inputs and then use a second for loop to print your output as in the second code